# Define is not a function with babel-polyfill and webpack on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, webpack, babeljs, imports-loader

I'm having an issue when deploying a React/Redux site to Azure App Service.
It builds and deploys fine, but when visiting the site I get JS errors for babel-polyfill - Uncaught TypeError: define is not a function.

We're using webpack with a few loaders and there is one in particular that I have a feeling could be the problem - imports-loader. We had it set as `use: 'imports-loader?define=>false'` which I believe overrides the define method. I tried this as true also but with no affect. I tried removing the `define=>false` altogether and the whole build broke...
See webpack config [here](https://pastebin.com/JEQwCwiJ).

Advice much welcome!

Cheers
Dave

Comment: Why are you using `imports-loader` there in the first place?

Comment: We picked up a pre-made template that used it and haven't looked at removing it. It may be a possibility though if it is giving this much grief!

Comment: Changed the build agent on VSTS to a MacOS agent as opposed to windows that it was using and it fixed the error. Also removed the imports-loader as it wasn't really being used so that's another nightmare removed! Cheers